# Application migration and apple id association

Tags: mac-appstore, apple-id, migration, migration-assistant

Used home sharing to grab my son's copy of iPhoto a few years ago.  Now I have a brand new MacBook and I used migration assistant to copy files to it.

An iPhoto update came out last week and I tried to install it but it wanted my son's apple id password, even though iPhoto came with the new macbook.

How can I change the iPhoto to belong to me and my apple id?  Or is there a way to restore it from the original macbook install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to uninstall (delete) the current iPhoto and re-download it from Mac App Store. You cannot update an app which does not belong to your Apple id. The re-downloaded iPhoto will recognize your previous iPhoto Library.

Comment: I put iPhoto in the trash and now App store  wants $14.99 for it.  I didn't buy it from the App Store - It came with the MacBook.

Comment: You can try one thing. Put back iPhoto into your Applications folder. Download any free app (eg. Twitter) from App Store. Right click on Twitter app and select Show Package Contents. Then open contents. Copy two folders named _CodeSignature and _MASReceipt and paste it inside the contents folder of iPhoto. Restart your Mac and go to Mac App Store. You should be able to update iPhoto now.